# Angular library module not found

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created an angular library and I am referencing this library in a separate external project. However, whenever I am referencing a new service that I have created I get the below error:

```
Module not found: Error: Package path ./lib/services/test.service is not exported from package D:\Projects\Admin\node_modules\my-lib (see exports field in D:\Projects\Admin\node_modules\my-lib\package.json)
```

I have added the service to the public-api.ts file but still no luck.

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

  constructor() { }

  getTest(): string{
    console.log('inside the service');
    return "This is inside the service";
  }
}
```

my-lib.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { myLibComponent } from './my-lib.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    myLibComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [
    myLibComponent
  ]
})
export class myLibModule { }
```

public-api.ts

```
export * from './lib/my-lib.service';
export * from './lib/my-lib.component';
export * from './lib/my-lib.module';
export * from './lib/services/test.service';
```

Moreover, when I use the default service that comes with the library it is compiling with no errors but when any of the functions are executed I get the below error on the console:

```
this.myLibService.doSomething is not a function
```

myLibService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class myLibService {

  constructor() { }

  doSomething(){
    console.log('do something');
  }
}
```

However using the selector of one of the components works fine.

```
<lib-myLib></lib-myLib>
```

app.module

```
import { myLibModule } from 'my-lib'; 


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    myLibModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Injecting the service

```
import { TestService } from 'my-lib';
 constructor(
    private testService: TestService
  ) {}

 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.testService.getTest();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to export all the modules, components and services that you intend to use in a file that is usually called `public-api.ts`
with this file you decide what part of your library will be exposed and which not.
if you google about it you will find a lot of examples and tutorials.

Comment: I have already added the services to the public-api.ts file. The weird thing is that it is working fine on VsCode it's even giving me autocomplete but it fails to compile when I save

Comment: try to export it like this in public-api `export { TestService } from './lib/services/test.service';` also could you show the code where you import the service

Comment: The code has been updated

Comment: I also have this issue. like, they are all in public_api.ts and no error shows up in my ide. but the errors shows up when i start the angular webapp.. i double checked and the classes/comp/service/etc exist but this error message persists